# Ajax load opens content in browser tab

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, window, refresh

I have a problem with a code. My code is working perfectly with my Teamspeak Viewer on my homepage, but I've tried the same with a different PHP file, it's showing the content and it's refreshing, but sometimes the php inside the div container opens automatically in the current browser tab. In my case the div content is jumping out the div and opens sc_frame.php and the link looks like this: https://example.net/sc_frame.php?_=1525978653152

Any Idea?

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#loaddiv').load('sc_frame.php');
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() 
    {
        $('#loaddiv').load('sc_frame.php');
    }, 5000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
}); 
</script>

<div id="loaddiv"></div>
```

Comment: `404` file not found

Comment: this is a example link, the important part is: sc_frame.php?_=1525978653152